# Sobreposição dos elementos do lado direito no rodapé

Tags: suporte, bug, status-pronto

Acredito que a imagem irá descrever a minha questão melhor do que mil palavras:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem algum propósito nisso? Existe alguma justificação? Ou ocorre apenas comigo?

**Quando ocorre:**

Detetei apenas quando tentava editar uma questão, e neste momento (enquanto esrevo esta questão) também esta a acontecer.

**Nota:**

Utilizo o Chrome.

Comment: Relacionado: [Lista de perguntas similares sobrepõe footer quando muito grande](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/553/3117)

Comment: O que eu faço é [injetar CSS pra esconder o troço](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2049/201) (e o rodapé também de lambuja). *Bye, bye... hasta luego!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devem ter dezenas de duplicatas sobre esse problema (com aspas?) em toda a rede. No Meta Stack Exchange tem uma série que até parece um *loop*:

- [*Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136849/185667)

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>
- [*Floating sidebar can get too long and obscure footer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110258/185667)

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>
- [*“Questions that may already have your answer” box overlaps onto the footer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159297/185667)

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>
- [*The suggestion bar on right side of the page is overlapping on the bottom menu area (footer)*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177591/185667)

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Na pergunta destino das duplicatas, a solicitação de novo recurso ou *bug report* foi marcado como [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E [respondido assim por um funcionário](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236369/185667):

> We think that sidebar is pretty important, and want it to remain visible. The footer, on the other hand, isn't that important, and can always be accessed again with a bit of scrolling up. It's not worth the time to tweak the page so that it's only scrollable until the point of overlap.

Tradução:

> Achamos que a barra lateral é bastante importante e deve permanecer visível. O rodapé, por outro lado, não é tão importante, e pode ser sempre acessado de novo com um pouco de rolagem para cima na página. Não é digno de nosso tempo fazer ajustes na página de maneira que só seja "rolável" até o ponto de sobreposição.

Comment: Solução estranha, mas prontos... No lo tiengo ma nada a reclamar. :d